# d3 arc creation not working with data binding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new into D3 and Javascript and I m trying to figure out why this code is not working. the error seems to be in the last anonymous function.Replacing it with `a` works

Any suggestion?

```
var pi = Math.PI;
var cornerRadius = 20;
var spaceAngle = 10

var percents = [40, 60, 76]

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

function deriveArcs(angle, i) {
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(180 + i * spaceAngle)
        .outerRadius(240 + i * spaceAngle)
        .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
        .startAngle(-pi * 0.5)
        .endAngle(-pi * 0.5 + angle / 100 * pi);
    return arc;
}

var a = deriveArcs(30, 0)

g.selectAll("path")
    .data(percents)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",
        function(d, i) {
            console.log(d+" "+i)
            var aa = deriveArcs(d, i);
            return aa;
        }
    );
```

Error in chrome :

> d3.min.js:1 Error:  attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function n(){var…".
>       a @ d3.min.js:1
>       (anonymous) @ d3.min.js:3
>       Y @ d3.min.js:1
>       Aa.each @ d3.min.js:3
>       Aa.attr @ d3.min.js:3
>       (anonymous) @ pie.js:30
>       pie.js:32 60 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `derivedArcs` function, when you do this:

```
return arc;
```

You are just returning the arc generator function itself, not its value.

That being said, it should be:

```
return arc();
```

Which **executes** the arc generator function and returns a proper path.

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
var pi = Math.PI;
var cornerRadius = 20;
var spaceAngle = 10

var percents = [40, 60, 76]

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


function deriveArcs(angle, i) {
  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(180 + i * spaceAngle)
    .outerRadius(240 + i * spaceAngle)
    .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
    .startAngle(-pi * 0.5)
    .endAngle(-pi * 0.5 + angle / 100 * pi);
  return arc();
}

var a = deriveArcs(30, 0)

g.selectAll("path")
  .data(percents)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",
    function(d, i) {
      return deriveArcs(d, i);
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Just in case, someone else comes here for the same reason, try this.

d3.svg.arc();